# How to override whole html with new html file using jquery

Tags: jquery, load

I'm trying to use jquery load function, but I can't get the whole content to override the html of current file that I'm loading the extern file from.

Let's see an example situation:
This the first page where on click I want to load a file.html

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <script>$(document).load("file.html");</script>
    </head>
    <body>
       Some stuff
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's example page I want to load:

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <script></script>

    </head>
    <body>
       Some stuff
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You'll have a much better chance of getting an answer if you post your existing code, explain what happens (or any error you get) and what you want to happen.

Comment: What errors are you getting? Where's your code?

Comment: I'm not getting any error, it just loads page without scripts included inside it and without <head> and <body> tags, therefore the javascripts on loaded page don't work.

Comment: Post a link or post some code that illustrates your issue, otherwise we can't do anything other than guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very simple:
`$('body').load('/your/file')`

but why doing this ?!

Comment: Because after I log in, I want the login page to disappear and load a new page without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 3):

In my understanding you'd like to render a different page. Then why don't you use `window.location`?

Like this:

```
window.location='http://www.google.com';
```

Comment: I don't want to refresh the page. I just wanna get rid of the current html and replace it with new.